# Servlet compile errors with Comparator interface

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java-8, comparator, abstract-methods

We are getting servlet compile errors on `Comparator` interface after upgrade from Java 1.7 to Java 1.8, using Netbeans and Weblogic 12c.  The `.jsp` files ran fine in Java 1.7.  I have read through other similar questions but have not found a solution.  I have tried checking the Weblogic Domain configuration JSP Compiler Backwards Compatible with no success. The methods that the compiler is complaining about are `default` methods so they should not need mentioned, correct?  Do the classes implementing `Comparator` need to be re written for Java 8? If so, please advise.

**Errors**

```
 viewFundCites.jsp:151:11: The type compareFundedPrOrderedByPr must implement the inherited abstract method Comparator.thenComparing(Function, Comparator)
    class compareFundedPrOrderedByPr implements Comparator {
          ^-----------------------^
```

**Code**

```
class compareFundedPrOrderedByPr implements Comparator {
    public int compare (Object a, Object b) {
        int ordering = 0;
        FundCite itemA = (FundCite)a;
        FundCite itemB = (FundCite)b;
        if ((null == itemA) && (null == itemB)) {
            ordering = 0;
        } else if ((null == itemA.getPrName()) && (null == itemB.getPrName())) {
            ordering = 0;
        } else if (null == itemA.getPrName()) {
            ordering = -1;
        } else if (null == itemB.getPrName()) {
            ordering = 1;
        } else {
            // Do primary sort by PR Name.
            ordering = itemA.getPrName().compareTo(itemB.getPrName());
            if (0 == ordering) {
                // Do secondary sort by CLIN.
                if ((null == itemA.getClin()) && (null == itemB.getClin())) {
                    ordering = 0;
                } else if (null == itemA.getClin()) {
                    ordering = -1;
                } else if (null == itemB.getClin()) {
                    ordering = 1;
                } else {
                    ordering = itemA.getClin().compareTo(itemB.getClin());
                }
            }
        }
        return ordering;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this message appear when your application is build and packaged in NetBeans, or in Weblogic log?

Comment: This message appears when trying to run the jsp.  There are no errors during build.

Comment: Then, probably, the following happens: you compile your classes with Java SE 1.8, then you deploy your application to WebLogic, then it tries to compile JSP pages and fails for some reason. Maybe the version of Java SE that is used to run WebLogic is not 1.8?

Comment: Netbeans compiles the code using jdk-8u74 and throws no errors. Weblogic uses the same jdk.  all other versions of java have been uninstalled.  This error is only in .jsp appearing at runtime.

Comment: I think, Java of an earlier (pre-1.8) version is somehow involved, but I do not know how exactly. If it was not, why would compiler complain about a `default` method.

Comment: The code base was developed and compiled using java 1.7.  This error is happening as we are trying to upgrade to java 1.8